# What packing material to use between a brick and house beam?

Tags: foundation, joists

I'm replacing a damaged beam under my house with bricks under each floor joist. The bricks are 15mm lower than the original beam. I've been told to use roof slates to pack the rest of the height.

I'm slightly skeptical due to slates being brittle. Could I use synthetic slates instead?

I've read about dry hard packed mortar but that isn't an option for me.

What other materials are used for packing in these instances?

Comment: When you say packing you are talking about supporting the beam, keeping it in place? Or are you talking about keeping it place temporarily? Or is it more cosmetic?

Comment: I'll remove the beam entirely, replacing the beam with a brick tower if you like for each floor joist (the joists are now resting on the beam that will be removed). So the bricks and packing will support the floor joists.

Comment: Any reason you're not just replacing the beam?

Comment: How tall are the brick "towers"?  It might make more sense to use [Jack Posts](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/building-materials-builders-hardware/tiger-brand-jack-post-super-s-8-ft-4-in-jack-post-117690.html#.UDZbPNaPU_w). They come in a variety of sizes, and are adjustable.

Comment: What is going to be supporting the bricks?  I'm assuming the beam you're removing is supported on each end by the foundation.  What will be under the brick towers, earth, concrete, something else?

Comment: @Tester101 The height is only 80mm (the height of the beam). The brick will be resting on the foundation. The beam at the moment is resting directly on the foundation as well. It goes all along the beam.

Comment: @Steven I'm replacing it with bricks so I don't have to rip the floor up to accommodate the beam. There's no other way into the crawl space apart from through the floor. I already have some floorboards taken up but not enough to get a new beam through. We've just restored the wood floor and only after realized that the beam had to be replaced.

Comment: A picture/drawing/diagram might be helpful.

Comment: @Johannes OK so this is what I'm picturing. You have a [beam on the foundation](http://i.imgur.com/jcFXo.png). Which you want to replace with bricks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/CjuFD.png)? But you're not sure what to fill the gap with, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stacked steel plates as shims. Use varying thickness's as required to ensure they are tightly packed and fully supporting the joist loads.

I'll assume the remaining structure of bricks and whatever is supporting them is properly designed and constructed, not just dry stacked (unless this is temporary, in which case do what ever works). If you live in a seismic area, the top of the bricks need to have a positive connection to the joists, not just shimmed. Your proposal sounds a bit sketchy on the surface, but it is possible to do this well and correctly, so I'll give you the benefit of any doubt and just answer your question.

Comment: Thanks bcworkz, yes steel is probably the way to go. I'm still considering just replacing the beam with a new one. If I can open the floor enough without breaking it that's what I'll end up doing. It's not a seismic area (London UK).

Comment: Steel works, but wouldn't wood shims be cheaper?  You can cut them the exact size you want, and even treat them if you think you need to.

Comment: @dbtracey You would trust some wooden shims to support the weight of the walls of your house?  Please tell me what you think would happen if you got them wet?  If there was a small seismic disturbance?

Answer (score 0):

Steel shims would be a good temporary solution but if it were myself and I only needed a few, then I would order custom size bricks to fit the gap perfectly.  It would be well worth the money and probably the only thing that would properly meet building codes in most areas and countries.